# Elasticsearch: How to forbid the analyzing for a certain data type (e.g. string)

Tags: elasticsearch

we gathering data(in json format) from user input. I want to know is there any way to forbid the analyzing process for certain data type(e.g. string), so that if we detect the value of some field is in string format, we will not analyze it, just leave it as a whole.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using index template,

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/_template/not_analyzed_template" -d'
{
    "template": "*", 
    "mappings": {
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "template_1": {
                        "mapping": {
                            "index": "not_analyzed",
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "match": "*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}'
```

just, do above request.

After that add data to es, string is not analyzed from now.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks, it works. we set "template": "PREFIX*" to avoid affecting other indexes.